# NuGet Package Manager - Json.Net- After installing once, cannot install again

Tags: visual-studio-2010, json.net, nuget-package

I was able to successfully download Json.NET via NuGet Package Manager. Then, I decided I wanted to move the functionality to a different project. So I deleted the current project package and went to download Json.NET again for the other project. I received this error message:

Operation Failed: 'Newtonsoft.Json' already has a dependency defined for 'Microsoft.CSharp'.

The error shows even when attempting to re-install on the project that originally worked. So after obtaining the package successfully once, I now can't download it at all.

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 (4.0 framework) and NuGet Package Manager 2.8.6. I have tried completely removing the package manager and reinstalling, but the same error remains. I can install other packages with no problem. It's just Json.NET.

Any ideas what could be causing this? Help is much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Been there: You need to use a package manager v2.10.x (iirc) because Json.Net nuget package depends on it.

Comment: Thanks! Can you direct me with a download link?

Comment: I'm stuck on this myself (VS 2012) but I'll post as soon as a find a workaround.

Comment: This happened to me few days back. I think we need to update nuget package manager. For some reasons I couldn't do it. If you don't bother about the version you can install 9.x.                          Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Version 9.0.1